# Entity Framework: Seeding data from the business layer

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I am using Entity Framework 6, and code first. I have a Data, Bus, App layers. I wan to seed my data from the business layer, without coupling it onto the Data layer.

The reason I would like to do it in the bus. layer is that some of the seed data is quite specific to the business logic, and I would like to use some of the logic in the bus. layer when I insert into the DB.

Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by:
EnableMigration -ProjectName DataProject -ContextProjectName BusinessProject

Works well!